# How to search string with apostrophe quote with XPATH in XML?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have following XML

```
$xml = <<<XML
<books>
 <book>
  <title>PHP Basic's</title>
  <author>Jim Smith</author>
  <author>Jane Smith</author>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>PHP Secrets</title>
  <author>Jenny Smythe</author>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>XML basics</title>
  <author>Joe Black</author>
 </book>
</books>
XML;
```

And following PHP Code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$books = $xml->xpath("//book[contains(title,'Basic's')]");
```

Question is: How to search for a string with apostrophe quote? I tried with either with like tried to quote entire XPATH expression with Single (') and Double (") quote but could not be able to create proper XPATH expression. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch `'` with `"` and escape the apostrophe in `Basic's`:

```
$books = $xml->xpath('//book[contains(title,"Basic\'s")]');
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/5I6s2A1E)

Comment: Thank you so much and also thumbs up for quick working example :)